# Getting element out of IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working through the amazing [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours) and have completed the core tasks and wanted to extend it but ran into problem. What I wanted to do is make `eval` function available to runtime, but have issue storing it into the global environment.

The runtime environment is of type:

```
type Env = IORef [(String, IORef LispVal)]
```

The Haskell `eval` implementation is of type:

```
eval :: Env -> LispVal -> IOThrowsError LispVal
```

The global environment is a mapping of type:

```
primitiveBindings :: IO Env
```

as it contain functions performing IO mixed with pure functions.  My attempt was to set the runtime `eval` to the host `eval` partially applied with global environment like this:

```
baseFun :: [(String, [LispVal] -> IOThrowsError LispVal)]
baseFun = [("eval", unaryOp (eval (liftIO $ readIORef primitiveBindings)))]
```

Where `unaryOp` is:

```
unaryOp :: (LispVal -> ThrowsError LispVal) -> [LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal
unaryOp f [v] = f v
```

I wanted to then add the elements into the global environment but I get a compile error of:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IORef a'
       against inferred type `IO Env'
In the first argument of `readIORef', namely `primitiveBindings'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `readIORef primitiveBindings'
In the first argument of `eval', namely
    `(liftIO $ readIORef primitiveBindings)'
```

It appear that this pattern of `readIORef env` happen often in the code, so it unclear why it's not working here.  I would greatly appreciate enlightenment in my errors.  For reference my code is almost exactly like the [final code for the original tutorial](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/scheme_in_48/code/listing10.hs) as a reference.

Thank you

Comment: It would be useful if you clarified the connection between `ThrowsError` and `IOThrowsError`. I went and looked it up and it looks like `ThrowsError` is `Either LispError` and `IOThrowsError` is `ErrorT LispError IO`, roughly speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `primitiveBindings` is *not* a global environment, but rather an action that, when performed, generates a fresh mapping with the primitive bindings already set up. Perhaps a better name for it would have been `createPrimitiveBindings`. There is no way to have proper globals in Haskell without `unsafePerformIO` hacks.

Therefore, the way you're trying to add `eval` would make it evaluate everything in a *new* environment, since you're re-running the `primitiveBindings` action. We can easily take care of the type errors, if that is indeed what you intended:

```
baseFun :: [(String, [LispVal] -> IOThrowsError LispVal)]
baseFun = [("eval", evalInNewEnv)]
    where evalInNewEnv args = do
              env <- liftIO primitiveBindings
              unaryOp (eval env) args
```

As you see, there is no need for any `readIORef` here, since `eval` already expects `Env` which just a type synonym for an `IORef`.

However, it sounds to me like you'd like `eval` to work in a "global" environment, in which case, you would need to have this environment passed to you somehow, since as I mentioned, there are no globals. For example, we can define something like this which would create a new environment with `eval` in it.

```
primitiveBindingsWithEval :: IO Env
primitiveBindingsWithEval = do
    env <- primitiveBindings    
    bindVars env [("eval", unaryOp (eval env))]
```

You can then replace existing uses of `primitiveBindings` with `primitiveBindingsWithEval` when you want a fresh environment with `eval` in it.

Comment: Your fixing of the type errors isn't quite right, since the return type of `unaryOp` doesn't support `IO`. You'll need to generalise the type of `unaryOp` before you can use it like that.

Comment: This answer and benmachine followup is what makes a click in my brain! As nice bonus this fixes problem I did not know I had had. I truly appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue (from the error message) is `readIORef primitiveBindings`.

Since `readIORef ::  IORef a -> IO a` and `primitiveBindings :: IO (IORef [(String, IORef LispVal)])` the types don't line up (notice `primitiveBindings` is wrapped in `IO`).

Try `primitiveBindings >>= readIORef`.

To the question in your title: you can't "get an element out of IO", since `IO` is the world, and haskell doesn't expose its implementation, so you're left with only the interface provided by `Monad` (bind and return). Someone can direct you to a better explanation of that point if needed.

Comment: Changing to `baseFun = [("eval", unaryOp (eval (primitiveBindings >>= readIORef)))]` gives the same type error with the reporting now in "In the first argument of `(>>=)'". Maybe I am missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: the type of `unaryOp` actually involves `IOThrowsError` everywhere you wrote `ThrowsError`. Then, just going by the types you've given without knowing the domain, I can make a guess about what you meant:

```
baseFun = [("eval", unaryOp (\lispVal -> liftIO primitiveBindings >>= flip eval lispVal))]
```

Does that look like it's reasonably close to what you wanted?

Comment: `IOThrowsError` and `ThrowsError` are different types. Admittedly `unaryOp` could be made much more polymorphic, in which case it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing `IO` and pure functions somewhat haphazardly. Essentially, you have three problems:

1. You want `unaryOp (eval (liftIO $ readIORef primitiveBindings))` to have type `[LispVal] -> IOThrowsError LispVal`, but `unaryOp` returns type `[LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal`, and `IOThrowsError` is not the same as `ThrowsError`. There are several ways to fix this, but by far the easiest is to generalise the type of `unaryOp`:

   ```
   unaryOp :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> b
   unaryOp f [v] = f v
   ```

   (You should probably also come up with a nicer error message for when the second argument isn't a singleton list.)

   Now `unaryOp` does what it did before, but can also return `[LispVal] -> IOThrowsError LispVal` if you give it `LispVal -> IOThrowsError LispVal`, which is exactly what `eval` *does* give it. So far so good. But:
2. `liftIO (readIORef primitiveBindings)` doesn't typecheck, because `primitiveBindings` isn't an `IORef`, it's an `IO` action that *yields* an `IORef` when run. So you can make an action that reads the `IORef` with `=<<`, i.e. `readIORef =<< primitiveBindings`, but in fact you don't *want* to do that because you want to pass the `IORef` itself to `eval`, not its contents. So you should just use `liftIO primitiveBindings` instead. But:
3. `eval` takes an argument of type `Env`, but `liftIO primitiveBindings` is type `IOThrowsError Env` (actually, it's more general than that, but that's close enough). So you'll need to use `>>=` or `do` to extract the value first:

   ```
   evalOp val = do
     env <- liftIO primitiveBindings
     eval env val

   baseFun = [("eval", unaryOp evalOp)]
   ```

As an aside, to address the tone of the question title: in Haskell, you don't get stuff out of `IO`. What you do is you write functions which you then put *into* `IO` to get more `IO` out. `>>=` (i.e. `do` notation) and `return` are the usual techniques for "lifting" functions to operate on `IO` values.

Comment: This is really kind of just a combination of the issues highlighted in the other answers, but no-one got a clear explanation of all three of them at once :P